# How to add 2nd sign in url at azure portal for a web app

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Even after adding url in refirect uri, we are getting reply uri is not configured.  Under F12 we see the auth request is trying to send redirect url as origin.*.com. 
For any url we give auth request is aensing origin as the reply url.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the correct one.( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How to add 2nd sign in url at azure portal for a web app?

Go to your application under App registrations->Authentication->Add a platform->Choose Web

[image]

Click Add URI to add URI.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Tony Ju. Yes we have added the url in reply url, then also we are getting same error. 
Can you suggest any tools or technique to debug the error? .  Do you know why origin.*.com is appearing in Authentication request ?

Comment: @naveenkumar What is your authentication url and how do you make the request?

Comment: @naveenkumar Did you configure the redirect url in your code?

Comment: my new url looks like https://migration-****-***.domain.com

Oldone(existing) https://***-***.domain.com

Comment: @naveenkumar I am a little confused about your issue. Were you trying to integrate Azure AD to your application?

Comment: Now the new migrated code is hosted in aws cloud front. This app is trying to authorize user using azure sso

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204428/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-and-tony-ju).

Answer (score 0):

By default aws will make the site names as origin.sirurl.
Once removing the origin it is working as expected